# How can I integrate Perl with ASP.NET Webforms?

Tags: asp.net, perl, webforms

I want to integrate some existing Perl code with ASP.NET. I see plenty examples of accessing Perl from .NET but nothing on the reverse. Has anyone had any experience attempting to do this or does everyone just recreate their existing Perl functionality in one fell swoop?

For more detail, I have some functionality already implemented in Perl that we want to integrate with a larger portal that we implemented in ASP.NET webforms. Rather than re-implementing the existing functionality in .NET, we want to have some pages of the portal render through Perl (allowing it to access WebForm session information without having to put it into a cookie). Going forward, all new code and updates to the Perl code will be implemented in .NET on a case by case basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way would be to get your perl code to call your asp pages, and then use Request.QueryString on the asp side to pull those variables in.